# Apple Code Sample: TouchCells, How Does it Work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sample

I've been working on custom UITableViewCells and came across the TouchCells example from apple: [TouchCells Example Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TouchCells/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008062-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

I can't figure out how the application loads.  If you look at `AppDelegate.m`, you see this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
// create window and set up table view controller
detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.loadView;

[window addSubview:navController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

which would seem to load a `DetailViewController`.

However, when the app loads, there is a `UITableViewController` of type `MyTableViewController` loaded with the Title `TouchCells`.  I looked at `MainWindow.xib` and there is no `MyTableViewController` (as far as I can tell).

When I put break points in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// load our data from a plist file inside our app bundle
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tableData"     ofType:@"plist"];
self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

of `MyTableViewController.m`, the breakpoint is hit before a breakpoint in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` from `AppDelegate.m`.  I guess this means the `MyTableViewController` is being loaded first, but I can't for the life of me figure out where that call is in the code.

Can anybody help me figure out the logical flow of the `TouchCells` example?

Thanks

**Answer**

The selected answer has the correct information in it, but the answer @Caleb provided shows how to get that information.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applicationDidFinishLaunching is called the interface builder connections will be set already. Therefore any class that needs to be initialized will be called before applicationDidFinishLaunching. If you are wondering as to what methods are calling it follow the stack trace once your break point is hit inside of the Debug Navigator in XCode 4.

**Update:**

Inside of MainWindow.xib expand the Navigation Controller and you will find MyTableViewController.

Comment: I can't find where `MyTableViewController` is declared.  It's not in `MainWindow.xib` nor in `AppDelegate.m`

Comment: It's in `MainWindow.xib`. Open the navigation controller. `MyTableViewController` is its root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Xcode 4, you can click the little expansion button at the bottom of the IB dock area:

[image: expansion button]

That'll let you see the objects contained in the navigation controller, like this:

[image: document structure]

Now you can see that a MyTableViewController is created as the navigation controller's root controller when the main nib is loaded. Another way to do this is to use the Editor->Reveal in Document Structure command.